# Unused argument error in shinyWidgets: airDatepickerInput

Tags: r, shiny, widget, date-range

I want to use the [airDatepickerInput](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.5.7/topics/airDatepicker) from [shinyWidgets](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.5.7). With the code below I am able to select a range between two dates, but I am not able to select the same date as start and end date. In the documentation of airDatepicker it is stated:

- **toggleSelected**: When TRUE, in range mode, it's not possible to select the same date as start and end.

As far as I understood with toggleSelected = FALSE I can select the same date as start and end, right?

However, if I comment out toggleSelected I got the error

```
Error in shinyWidgets::airDatepickerInput("daterange", "Date range:",  : 
  unused argument (toggleSelected = FALSE)
```

no matter if toggleSelected is true or false.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyWidgets::airDatepickerInput("daterange", "Date range:",
                                   range = TRUE,
                                   todayButton = TRUE,
                                   # toggleSelected = FALSE,
                                   value = c("2010-01-01", "2001-12-31")
                                   ),
  verbatimTextOutput("res")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res <- renderPrint({
    paste("Start at", input$daterange[1], "and end at", input$daterange[2])
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How do I prevent the error and/or am able to select the same date as start and end?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.

I can run your code with `value=c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-01")` and I get a range with the same date as the start and end of the range in `output$res`.  But there seems to be no way of selecting the same date as the start and end of the range having *started* with a range that spans more than one day.

If I set `range=FALSE`, I can select one date in the `datepickerInput` but then can't expand to a range, for obvious reasons.

I get the error you quote when I set `range` to `FALSE` and then *uncomment* `toggleSelected=FALSE`.

At first glance, it looks as if you can use the input in range mode and have a range that spans at least two days *or* run it in single date mode and select just one day.  Thus, it looks as if you need a programmatic way to toggle between the two.  That's certainly possible, but it might make for a more appealing GUI of you had three inputs: two `datepickerInput`s, each in single value mode and a check box labelled (say) "Permit range", and use some logic in the server function to disable/hide the `datepickerInput` for the end of the range when the checkbox is not selected.

Not an answer to your question as asked, but hopefully helpful all the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway. For now I use [dateRangeInput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/dateRangeInput.html) but the problem is, that here [the end date can be located before the start date](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2043). I want to keep things simple avoid multiple inputs. The airDatepickerInput in my opinion is a bit more easy to use than the dateRangeInput.